# Not able to get SSE message send back from server .net core C# to React js Frontend

Tags: .net-core, server-sent-events

Once i run react js project i am getting call for the Get api of SSE, then the connection is established and even the connection is open but the messages sent from Post SSE api call or even the  await responseStreamWriter.WriteLineAsync($"data: Welcome, {userId}!");
is not sending message to Frontend

I am testing SSE in localhost, not deployed frontend or backend to server.

Frontend - React JS ,Version: 18.2.0
Backend - .netcore C# - Version: 6.0

Frontend Code -
const SSEComponent = ({ userId }) => {
const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventSource = new EventSource(`https://localhost:7021/api/v1/payment/sse/${userId}`);

    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
      const newEvent = event.data;
      console.log("New Evevnts - ", newEvent);
      setEvents((prevEvents) => [...prevEvents, newEvent]);
    };

    eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('SSE Error:', error);
      eventSource.close();
    };

    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
    };
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>SSE Component for User: {userId}</h2>
      <ul>
        {events.map((event, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{event}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SSEComponent;
```

Backend -
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/payment/sse")]
public class SSEController : ControllerBase
{
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpResponse> _sseClients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpResponse>();
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<(string UserId, string Message)> _messageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<(string UserId, string Message)>();

```
    [HttpGet("{userId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ConnectSse(string userId)
    
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"] == "text/event-stream")
        {
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
            Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

            var responseStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(Response.Body, Encoding.UTF8);

            _sseClients.TryAdd(userId, Response);

            // Send a welcome message
            await responseStreamWriter.WriteLineAsync($"data: Welcome, {userId}!");

            // Keep the connection open
            while (!HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000); // Adjust delay as needed
                await responseStreamWriter.WriteLineAsync($"data: Server message to {userId} at {DateTime.UtcNow}");
                await responseStreamWriter.FlushAsync();
            }

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid request. SSE expected.");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost("{userId}")]
    public IActionResult SendMessage(string userId, [FromBody] string message)
    {
        if (_sseClients.TryGetValue(userId, out var clientResponse))
        {
            var responseStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(clientResponse.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
            responseStreamWriter.WriteLineAsync($"data: Message from server to {userId}: {message}");
            responseStreamWriter.FlushAsync();
        }

        return Ok("Message sent.");
    }
}
```

Expecting the message to get in React js console and UI, which are sent from backend through SSE